# What is the purpose of an Azure Subscription Alias?

Tags: azure

I recently stumbled upon subscription aliases in Azure.
However, I do not understand what their actual purpose is, or how to utilize them.

Despite the documentation on how to manage aliases via [ARM Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.subscription/aliases?tabs=json) or [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account/alias?view=azure-cli-latest), I only found the [AzureSubscriptionVendingFunction project on GitHub](https://github.com/jtracey93/AzureSubscriptionVendingFunction#azure-subscription-alias---explained) talking about Subscription Aliases. This section sounds interesting (esp. the distinct RBAC stuff), but still I don't get what aliases are really about.

*Edit: Fixed link to Azure CLI Account Alias documentation*

Comment: The Azure CLI alias is a different beast: it allows cli command aliases, these are not subscription aliases

Comment: Here are some use cases: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/6024207-allow-us-to-alias-the-subsciption-name-from-within

Comment: I linked the wrong CLI page. Apologies. This is the [right page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account/alias?view=azure-cli-latest).